# Python: X marks the trail (2d list)

Tags: python, error-handling

I've got a task to write code for this problem:

You're familiar with the story of Hansel and Gretel, so when you decide to go exploring you always make sure to keep track of where you've come from. Since you know how unreliable leaving a trail of breadcrumbs is, you decide to write a program to help you map out your trail.

Your program should first read in the size of the grid that you will be exploring, and then read in directions: left, right, up or down. You always start exploring at the top left of your map. After every step, you should print out the trail, reading in directions until a blank line is entered.

Your program should work like this:

Grid size: 3
x..
...
...
Direction: right
xx.
...
...
Direction: down
xx.
.x.
...
Direction: right
xx.
.xx
...
Direction:
​
You will never be directed off the edges of the map.

And so far I have written

```
table = []
line = input('Grid size: ')

for i in range(int(line)):
  row = []
  for i in range(int(line)):
    row.append('.')
  table.append(row)
table[0][0] = 'x'

for y in table:
  print(''.join(y))

x = int(0)
y = int(0)
direction = input('Direction: ')
while direction:
  if direction.lower() == 'right': 
    y = y+1                           #error here
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  elif direction.lower() == 'left':
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  elif direction.lower() == 'up':
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  elif direction.lower() == 'down':
    x = x+1
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  for y in table:
    print(''.join(y))
  direction = input('Direction: ')
```

But every time I run it and choose the direction right (just testing with one direction for now) it lets me do it once correctly then returns an error.

Example:

```
Grid size: 4
x...
....
....
....
Direction: right
xx..
....
....
....
Direction: right
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 19, in <module>
    y = y+1
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I have tried everything I can online and nothing is helping. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If `y` is a list, what do you intend `y + 1` to mean?

Comment: `for y in table` - you're overwriting your integer variable `y` with the loop iteration value (a row in the table)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a naming problem.
You use `y` as an integer to indicate the column and then you override `y`, and set it to a list in a `for` loop. When the code returns to the beginning of your `while`, `y` is a `list` and not an `int`, hence the error.

this should work:

```
table = []
line = input('Grid size: ')

for i in range(int(line)):
  row = []
  for i in range(int(line)):
    row.append('.')
  table.append(row)
table[0][0] = 'x'

for y in table:
  print(''.join(y))

x = int(0)
y = int(0)
direction = input('Direction: ')
while direction:
  if direction.lower() == 'right': 
    y = y+1                        
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  elif direction.lower() == 'left':
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  elif direction.lower() == 'up':
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  elif direction.lower() == 'down':
    x = x+1
    table[x][y] = 'x'
  for row in table:  # Changed the name from `y` to `row`
    print(''.join(row))
  direction = input('Direction: ')
```

Comment: @nokia Thanks, it worked! I thought I had looked at everything but I didn't check the last 3 lines of code because they worked earlier. Forgot about that variable name. While I'm here, does using y = y+1 and y += 1 make any practical difference here, should I always use one one coding becuase its better or is it not important at this point. Thanks again.